# Architecture for luigi tasks with multiple inputs

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, luigi

I have number of pickle files, one for each date between 2005 and 2010. Each file contains a dictionary of words with their respective frequencies for that date. I also have a "master file" with all unique words for the whole period. There are about 5 million words in total.

I need to take all that data and produce one CSV file per word, which will have one row per date. E.g., for example file `some_word.txt`:

```
2005-01-01,0.0003
2005-01-02,0.00034
2005-01-03,0.008
```

I'm having trouble organizing this process with the luigi framework. My current top-level task takes a word, looks up it's associated frequency for every date and stores the result in a CSV file. I guess I could just loop through every word in my master file and run the task with that word, but I estimate that would take months, if not longer. Here's my top-level `AggregateTokenFreqs` task in a simplified version.

```
class AggregateTokenFreqs(luigi.Task):
    word = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        pass  # not sure what to require here, master file?

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('data/{}.csv'.format(self.word))

    def run(self):
        results = []
        for date_ in some_list_of_dates:
            with open('pickles/{}.p'.format(date_), 'rb') as f:
                freqs = pickle.load(f)
                results.append((date_, freqs.get(self.word))

        # Write results list to output CSV file
```

Comment: What is the ongoing processing that you need to do? For example, is your plan to re-run the daily process when data for a new day arrives? If you only need to run it once, it probably doesn't make sense to run luigi. You'd be better off using multiprocessing in any case.

Answer (score 0):

@MattMcKnight says you might be better using multiprocessing. However if you want to use Luigi here's what you can do:

- Luigi has the concept of workers that you configure. That's the number of local process to run different task in parallel.
- You can model the task instead of "looping" through all the pickles, pass one single pickle to the task (as parameter). You will have to write the result to a TSV in a directory with an unique name.
- The have a loop that create a task per each pickle (date). An configure the number of workers (i.e. 5). that way you would be able to process 5 files at the same time.
- You will require an additional task that "joins" all the individual CSV files into one.

Hope this helps.